# How can I list the common elements of two lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, assignment

The elements of both lists are given as

A={9,5,9,3}, B={9,9,5,5}

In this case, how can I list the list {9,5,9} of the common elements of the two lists?

(The order does not matter.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need the duplicate `9` in the output:

```
 In[1]:= Flatten[KeyValueMap[ConstantArray, Merge[KeyIntersection[Counts /@ {{9, 5, 9, 3}, {9, 9, 5, 5}}], Min]], 1]
Out[1]:= {9, 9, 5}
```

If you didn't need the duplicate `9` you could just use the `Intersection` function.

Comment: Thank you.












































 It was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {9, 5, 9, 3};

b = {9, 9, 5, 5};
```

Using `DeleteElements` and `SymmetricDifference` (both new in 13.1)

```
DeleteElements[a, SymmetricDifference[a, b]]
```

{9, 5, 9}

Another test:

```
a = {0, 9, 5, 9, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7};

b = {9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 8};

DeleteElements[a, SymmetricDifference[a, b]]
```

{0, 9, 5, 9}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {9, 5, 9, 3};

b = {9, 9, 5, 5};
```

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[a, Alternatives @@ DeleteCases[a, Alternatives @@ b]]

(*{9, 5, 9}*)
```

Grabbing the @eldo's second test:

```
a = {0, 9, 5, 9, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7};

b = {9, 9, 5, 5, 0, 8};

DeleteCases[a, Alternatives @@ DeleteCases[a, Alternatives @@ b]]

(*{0, 9, 5, 9}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ResourceFunction` [IntersectionWithDuplicates](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntersectionWithDuplicates/):

```
A = {9, 5, 9, 3};
B = {9, 9, 5, 5};

ResourceFunction[
 "IntersectionWithDuplicates"][A,B]
```

---

> {5,9,9}

---

The function admittedly sorts the output as stated in the description.